# Bing Map V8 Infobox causing error

Tags: jquery, bing-maps

I am trying to migrate Bing Map V7 to V8 while doing that I am facing issue for displaying Info Box which is giving error for Map SDK after displaying info box.
Code Snippet from the Application:

```
        function DisplayLoc(e) {
                var map = null;
                var pinInfobox = null;
                var pinInfoBox; // the pop up info box
                var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
                var pinLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
                var pins = statewithcities;
                map = new 
               Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('bing_map'), {
                    mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
                    showDashboard: false,
                    enableSearchLogo: false,
                    enableClickableLogo: false,
                    showMapTypeSelector: false,
                    showScalebar: false,
                    disablePanning: false,
                    disableZooming: false,
                    showBreadcrumb: false,
                    disableBirdseye: true,
                    showCopyright: false,
                    credentials: mapID
                });
                 pinInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new 
                  Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), {
                    visible: false,
                    titleClickHandler: InfoboxHandler
                });
                infoboxLayer.push(pinInfobox);
                $.each(pins, function(index, pin) {
                 var pinLocation = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(
                 pin.latitude, pin.longitude)
                   NewPin.metadata.Title = pin.zipCode; 
                    NewPin.metadata.Id = pin.state;
                    NewPin.metadata.Description = "test";
                    pinLayer.push(NewPin); // add pushpin to pinLayer
           Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(NewPin, 'click',displayInfobox);
                    map.entities.push(NewPin);
                });
                map.entities.push(pinInfobox);
               function displayInfobox(e) {
                if(e.target.metadata){
                  pinInfobox.setOptions({
                        id: e.target.metadataId,
                        title: e.target.metadata.Title,
                        description: e.target.metadata.Description,
                        visible: true,
                        offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 0),
                        location:e.target.getLocation()
                    });
                }
              }
```

Please check and help me out as I am not sure where the error is  after following the Bing Documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following lines of code:

```
infoboxLayer.push(pinInfobox);

map.entities.push(pinInfobox);
```

Add the following the following line of code after creating the infobox.:

```
pinInfobox.setMap(map);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,it is working fine now but info box ins not aligned with pushpin.Can you please help me with that

Comment: Try removing or adjusting `offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 0),`